# Renaming and versioning image uploads in php

Tags: php

So I have an image upload page in my forum. If an image already exists, the old version is renamed to file.ext,timestamp (instead of being overwritten). I want the old, renamed version to have the correct extension (.jpg) so my gallery script can recognize old versions of the picture.

I think this the critical code:

```
if (IsEnabled($EnableUploadVersions, 0))
  @rename($filepath, "$filepath,$Now");
```

How can i change this for my purpose?
Thank you for help. :)

```
     UploadAuth($pagename, $auth);
  $uploadfile = $_FILES['uploadfile'];
  $upname = @$_REQUEST['upname'];
  if ($upname=='') $upname=$uploadfile['name'];
  $upname = MakeUploadName($pagename,$upname);
  if (!function_exists($UploadVerifyFunction))
    Abort('?no UploadVerifyFunction available');
  $filepath = FmtPageName("$UploadFileFmt/$upname",$pagename);
  $result = $UploadVerifyFunction($pagename,$uploadfile,$filepath);
  if ($result=='') {
    $filedir = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#','',$filepath);
    mkdirp($filedir);
    if (IsEnabled($EnableUploadVersions, 0))
      @rename($filepath, "$filepath,$Now");
    if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadfile['tmp_name'],$filepath))
      { Abort("?cannot move uploaded file to $filepath"); return; }
    fixperms($filepath, $UploadPermAdd, $UploadPermSet);
    if ($LastModFile) { touch($LastModFile); fixperms($LastModFile); }
    $result = "upresult=success";
    $FmtV['$upname'] = $upname;
    $FmtV['$upsize'] = $uploadfile['size'];
    if (IsEnabled($RecentUploadsFmt, 0)) {
      PostRecentChanges($pagename, '', '', $RecentUploadsFmt);
    }
    if (IsEnabled($NotifyItemUploadFmt, 0) && function_exists('NotifyUpdate')) {
      $NotifyItemFmt = $NotifyItemUploadFmt;
      $IsUploadPosted = 1;
      register_shutdown_function('NotifyUpdate', $pagename, getcwd());
    }
```

Comment: Where does your `$Now` variable come from? Could you just add ".jpg" onto the end of that when you create it? Failing that, you can check the doc for the `rename()` function and see that the second parameter is the new filename, and add it in there. It might be better to get the old extension out of the filename, unless your system prevents anything other than `.jpg` files from being uploaded.

Comment: Thank you. $Now is a Unix-style timestamp, this works properly. As i only use .jpg, i added: @rename($filepath, "$filepath,$Now".jpg);  but it still outputs: file.jpg,1631692429

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get an error message, surely the ".jpg" should be __inside__ the quotes? Is a comma a good idea in a filename? If I were doing it, I'd split the filename into the two parts, and add the `$now` at the end of the filename, not the filetype. Then it would be something like `file_1631692429.jpg` which seems somehow "better", for some reason.